# Can Stack Exchange sites generate pages that link directly to a specific answer?

Tags: support, answers, hyperlinks

I would like to be able to provide a link directly to an answer within a page without having to tell someone how to scroll down to the answer of interest.  Is this possible or do the StackExchange developers have to implement pages that use links like the following:

[HTML Link Locations](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_locations)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just click on the "share" link for any answer. This will give you a little popup that contains a link that points directly to the answer. If, for example, you want to link to the famous answer to [the question about parsing HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/1535629):

[image]

As you can see, this gives you a link directly to the answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1535629). If you don't want to reveal your user ID number, delete all the stuff after the last `/` (so, in this example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454). Note that removing your user ID from the link prevents you from earning the Announcer, Booster, and Publicist badges.

Comment: That's awesome!  Thanks.  Oh, and thanks for sharing that, umm, strange SO answer.